# The proof of a major theorem in Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory

> Let $f(x)\in K[x]$ be a separable polynomial of degree $n$. If $K$ does not have characteristic $2$, the Galois group of $f(x)$ over $K$ is a subgroup of $A_n$ if and only if disc $f$ is a square in $K$.

I've looked for the proof of this theorem everywhere. No luck until now. I would be grateful to anyone who could point me to the proof. Thanks!

Comment: See for instance [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf), pages 47-48.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723406/for-f-in-mathbbqx-galf-subset-s-n-is-a-subset-of-a-n-iff-deltaf