# For $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, Gal($f)\subset S_n$ is a subset of $A_n$ iff $\Delta(f)$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, permutations, galois-theory

Let $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ a monic irreducible polynomial, and Gal($f$) be a subgroup of $S_n$. How do I prove that

> Gal($f$) $\subset A_n\iff \Delta(f)$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}^*$?

I know what all these definitions mean, but to be really honest I don't even see where to begin this proof. Maybe somebody can help me in the right direction?

Comment: Instead of "quadratic"  perhaps you meant "A square" ?

Comment: @Joanpemo I think I do, thanks for noticing :)

Comment: See [here](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf), p. 47.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r_1,\dots,r_n$ be the roots of $f$ in some splitting field $E$. Then $\Delta(f)=D(f)^2$ in $E$, where
$$ D(f)=\prod_{i<j}(r_i-r_j) $$

What happens to $D(f)$ if you permute the roots?

Comment: Then you multiply $D(f)$ by $-1$ for each permutation?

Comment: If $\sigma$ is the permutation, then applying $\sigma$ to the roots multiplies $D(f)$ by $\mathrm{sign}(\sigma)$.

Comment: Okay, but how does this fact help me?

Comment: If the Galois group is contained in $A_n$, then $\sigma(D(f))=D(f)$ for all $\sigma$ in the Galois group, hence $D(f)\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Dont you mean then $D(f)\in\mathbb{Q}^*$?

Comment: Yes, clearly it's non-zero.

Comment: Okay, thankyou!